# What is "the issue" with variable qualifier placement?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, qualifiers

In [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226), under the section labeled "Variable Qualifiers", Apple says:

> You should decorate variables correctly. When using qualifiers in an object variable declaration, the correct format is:

```
ClassName * qualifier variableName;
```

> for example:

```
MyClass * __weak myWeakReference;
MyClass * __unsafe_unretained myUnsafeReference;
```

> Other variants are technically incorrect but are “forgiven” by the compiler. To understand the issue, see http://cdecl.org/.

Looking at cdecl.org doesn't clarify anything.  Can anyone explain what "the issue" they are referring to is?  In other words, help me convince others that this actually matters in a way that isn't just "because this one readme says so."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my examples with gibberish to English translations

It is well known that

```
ClassName * const varName; //varName is a constant pointer to ClassName
```

has different meaning than

```
const ClassName * varName; //varName is a pointer to constant ClassName
```

or

```
ClassName const * varName; //varName is a pointer to constant ClassName
```

In the same way this declaration

```
ClassName * __weak varName; //varName is a weak pointer to ClassName
```

and this declaration

```
__weak ClassName * varName; //varName is a pointer to weak?? ClassName??
```

are VERY different. However, the meaning of the second one is clear (although it's technically incorrect) and it can be "forgiven" by the compiler.

The correctness is a bit more important once you start working with pointers to pointers (e.g. `Foo * __autoreleasing *`).

I assume they wanted to protect beginner developers from the C/C++ declaration gibberish. Having the qualifier in the beginning seems more natural.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to read these right-to-left. So, for example `ClassName * __weak variableName` would read as "_variableName_ is a weak pointer to a _ClassName_" Or for `char const * string` you get "string is a pointer to const chars"

Comment: I know how to read them :) Right-to-left works only for the simplest ones :)

Comment: I assumed so, I meant my comment as additional background to your answer