# __block storage type without a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I was looking at the following code in the book **IOS7 Programming Pushing the Limits** and could not understand why the author used the `__block` storage type without using a block. My knowledge of `__block` is limited to the understanding that they allow a variable that is captured in scope by a block to be mutable. I have read some other SO posts about `__block`, but they confused me even more.

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

  self.layer = [CALayer layer];
  self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(80, 100, 160, 160);
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.layer];

  float scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, scale);
  [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];

  __block UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage,
                                                     CGRectMake(self.layer.frame.origin.x * scale,
                                                                self.layer.frame.origin.y * scale,
                                                                self.layer.frame.size.width * scale,
                                                                self.layer.frame.size.height * scale));
  image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
  image = [image applyBlurWithRadius:50.0f
                           tintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.1]
               saturationDeltaFactor:2.0f
                           maskImage:nil];

  self.layer.contents = (__bridge id)(image.CGImage);
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for using `__block` in this code. Could be a copy & paste error.

Comment: And it's [in the wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765950/what-is-the-issue-with-variable-qualifier-placement).

Comment: For academic purposes, distinct from the question asked, does anyone know whether will this cause `image` (the variable itself, not the thing it points to, obviously) to live on the heap? Or is the compiler smart enough to spot that if the thing is never even potentially captured then it can live on the stack like a normal local variable?

Comment: This code leaks, too.

Comment: @Tommy, good question. Knowing how smart the LLVM compiler is, I'd put my money on it not transferring the variable to the heap until it's needed there.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: It's in the right place. `__block` is a storage qualifier for variables, unlike `__weak` and `__strong` which are ownership qualifiers which are part of a pointer type.

Comment: @Tommy: In the current implementation, `__block` variables start on the stack, like blocks; only when a block that uses it is copied, does the `__block` variable data structure get moved to the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it's an editing error. The code probably did contain a block at one point, but it was removed in a later edit, but the author forgot to take away the __block qualifier.